# CoreImage: Create a CIImage with solid color and display it in NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image

I want to programatically generate a rectangular image with a solid color fill.
How can I do this?
I want to populate inputImageView with inputImage.

Here's my code so far, but all I get is an empty image view:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib{
  CIColor *red = [CIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0];
  CIImage *redImage = [CIImage imageWithColor:red];

  NSCIImageRep *ir = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:redImage];

  [self setInputImage:[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: NSMakeSize(25, 25)]];
  //magic should be happening right here!
  [[self inputImage] addRepresentation:ir];
  [[self inputView] setImage:[self inputImage]];
  [inputView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: What's the class this -awakeFromNib belongs to, and Where's your -drawRect: code?

Comment: The class is just the AppDelegate. No drawrect. The main thing I need to do is create a NSImage object.

Comment: Do you want an NSImage or a CIImage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(25, 25)];
[image lockFocus];
[[NSColor redColor] setFill];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 25, 25)];
[image unlockFocus];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, this is a perfect answer to the question. Ultimately, I want to use the image as an input to a Core Image filter.  So, I guess I really need both.  Can you help me create a CIImage as well?

Comment: Yep, I had seen that.  Wouldn't it be less expensive to generate the CIImage first?

Comment: Are you doing this so many thousands of times per second that it matters?